# How can I get Class object for every class in a jar

Tags: java, reflection, jar, introspection

I have a jar file with 30 or so classes. What I want is that at the beginning of the main method I invoke a class from within this jar which using Java's reflection capabilities gets `Class` references to each class in the jar. My ultimate goal is to perform some sort of operation, querying a variable which is defined for every class. Basically I'm looking for something like. Is there an easy way to do this using the standard reflection APIs or it will be too much of a hassle to make a working solution?

```
List l = Reflection.getAllClasses();
String var;
foreach(Class c : l) { 
    var = c.getField("fieldname");
    doSomething(var);
}
```

Edit:

Just to make it clear: The code will be executed from withing the inspected jar.

Comment: Why not include a list (e.g. using a `Properties` file) of classes in the Jar file when it is made?  +1 for stating the end goal.

Comment: @AndrewThompson because i don't want to bear this management burden - always remembering the list of files.

Comment: It would be trivial to write a class that prepares the list as part of the build process.  No burden at all.

Comment: @LordDoskias    did you ever get this to run with a jar not on the classpath?  Can you post your solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This does the trick for me:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;


public class ClassFinder
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
    Collection<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();

    JarFile jar = new JarFile("/home/nono/yamts/yamts.jar");
    for (Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries() ; entries.hasMoreElements() ;)
    {
        JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
        String file = entry.getName();
        if (file.endsWith(".class"))
        {
            String classname = file.replace('/', '.').substring(0, file.length() - 6);
            try 
            {
                Class<?> c = Class.forName(classname);
                classes.add(c);
            }
            catch (Throwable e) 
            {
                System.out.println("WARNING: failed to instantiate " + classname + " from " + file);
            }
        }
    }

    for (Class<?> c : classes)
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: but this will work for an external jar files. What if the aforementioned code is going to be executed withing the same jar as the target ? Edit: Also your code doesn't work for me. For every class I get "failed to instantiate"

Comment: As long as the jar is in the classpath, you can retrieve the class definition. If the specified jar is not in the classpath, then you'll probably need to invest extra work for a custom class loader.

Comment: @dagnelies does this code work?  I too continue to get failed to instantiate...  Exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com....someclass when i run with a jar not on the classpath and with it on the classpath

Comment: @ALM: no idea, it did in 2011. Perhaps something changed slightly since then. You're welcome to investigate and enhance the answer. From my comment above, the jar has apparently to be in the classpath.

Comment: @dagnelies      NP I figured it out yesterday after posting :)

I will post another answer.

Answer (score 2):

Listing all classes in a JAR file is not something that can be done with reflection.

However, it can be done using a [`JarInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html).

Comment: And also without a JarInputStream, by using JarFile (as the accepted answer demonstrates) :)

Comment: @Grodriguez JarInputStream can be used with a InputStream without saving JAR to filesystem e.g. `new JarInputStream(new URL("https://example.com/my.jar").openStream())`... I could not find a way to do that with JarFile. This answer is certainly useful.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution will work with a `jar` that is in your `classpath` or outside your `classpath`.

```
 try {
        File pathToJar = new File("C:/some.jar");

        JarFile jarFile;
            jarFile = new JarFile(pathToJar);
        Enumeration<JarEntry> e = jarFile.entries();

        URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:file:" + pathToJar+"!/") };
        URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);

        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry je = e.nextElement();
            if(je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class")){
                continue;
            }
            // -6 because of .class
            String className = je.getName().substring(0,je.getName().length()-6);
            className = className.replace('/', '.');
            System.out.println("Checking for class " + className);
            Class c = cl.loadClass(className);


            System.out.println("Class object " + c.getName());

        }
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```